# How do I get rid of the scrollbar near my pagination options on the bottom of my Material UI Table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

[image]

I tried messing around with the width and aspect ratio of my table, however, that did not solve the issue. There is adequate space for all of the pagination options thus I do not know why the scrollbar is there in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

To hide scrollbars use the css property `overflow: "hidden"`
or
[Specifically for MUI](https://mui.com/system/display/)

Comment: I tried using this property but it does not get rid of the scrollbar because I think the overflow property only applies to scrollbars that appear with data in the table rather than with the pagination options

Comment: Try assigning it to your upmost parent container #app or #root